# What causes old rep to evaporate?

Tags: support, reputation

I ran a rep audit a few weeks back, and another today, and see that some answers not changed in more than a year have shed up-votes.

Is this a result of the votes of deleted accounts being removed?

Details:  Ran an audit on 22nd October - post [1652711](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652680/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-that-is-piped-to-another-process-in-bash/1652711#1652711) had 4 upvotes, now has 3; post [1850693](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850673/using-sqlite-from-objective-c/1850693#1850693) had 3 upvotes, now has 2.

Comment: ...just a wild guess: could this be due to deleted users? (And just to prove the post itself had indeed a score of 4, so it was not the report that was off: Google cache still [shows](http://i.imgur.com/xGy40.png) a score of 4 [on 1 Nov 2010 03:20:58 GMT](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7_YCKLfwgWgJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/1652680/).)

Comment: I wish I could answer only to titles...

Answer (score 2):

It could be the result of merged accounts. If a user was logging in under two different accounts, upvoted your post from both of them, then had their accounts merged, I'm fairly certain one of the redundant votes would be removed.

Comment: Interesting - I wonder why someone would do that though... it's not like these were particularly special answers.

Comment: It could be something innocent, like a user logging in anonymously (i.e. without an OpenID) from multiple computers. Since they'd have a different account on each computer, they might upvote the post from one account, then see their upvote gone when logged in from the other and upvote again. It could have just been by accident.

Comment: I see... Quite neat that that all gets tidied up.